# How can I avoid gaps below a UICollectionView search bar on devices with notches?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, nslayoutconstraint

I have a `UICollectionView` with contents that I want to scroll below the transparent navigation bar. I also have a `UIView` that contains a `UISearchBar` that the user can toggle by tapping a button on the navigation bar:

[image: UICollectionView with contents that scroll below the transparent nav bar and custom search bar]

As the image above shows, this works well for a device without a notch. I achieve this by setting the content inset top to `searchController.searchBar.frame.size.height` and the content offset top to `-collectionView.contentInset.top - (navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height ?? 0) - UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height)`.

For a device with a notch, there is a gap between the search bar and the contents when the search bar is first displayed. Then, when I start searching, the spacing is correct. If I cancel and the contents don't fit on the screen (that is, the collection view is scrollable), there's a gap the size of the search bar. If the contents do fit on the screen, there is no such gap.

[image: UICollectionView with contents that scroll below the transparent nav bar and custom search bar on device with notch]

The constraints are set in the storyboard. The only way I could find to get the behavior I wanted was to constrain the collection view top to the top layout guide bottom - 64 which is certainly not ideal.

Clearly, something is wrong with my mental models here. How do I get the desired behavior on devices with and without notches and ideally avoid the magic number in the constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is due to **safe area layout guides**. For device with notch, top constraint calculates distance from Safe Area(starting from notch).

To solve this, go to storyboard -> select CollectionView -> select top constraint. You will see few options related to constraint on Size inspector. Change Second Item to **SuperView** instead of **Safe Area**.

[screenshot of size inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7IR1.png)

Comment: Thank you, @Bhaumik! That does solve my problem and other issues I was having in landscape -- I love a simple solution. I can only wonder why I didn't notice that!

Comment: I'm glad that it helped you out @HélèneMartin!